# Autohotkey : Unable to map RCtrl + Rshift + Tab : Getting syntax error

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I'm a new Autohotkey user. I'm trying to remap keys for use with Outlook.

```
RCtrl & Tab::
WinGet, Active_ID, ID, A
WinGet, Active_Process, ProcessName, ahk_id %Active_ID%
if (Active_Process = "Outlook.exe") {
    Send !4
}
else {
    Send ^{tab}
}
return

RCtrl & RShift & Tab::
WinGet, Active_ID, ID, A
WinGet, Active_Process, ProcessName, ahk_id %Active_ID%
if (Active_Process = "Outlook.exe") {
    Send !5
}
else {
    Send ^+{tab}
}
return
```

The first mapping works just as I want (so far (: ), however the second one gives me an error saying : Invalid Hotkey

I tried googling for this, but couldn't find the right way to map the combination of RCtrl & Rshift & Tab.

For some background, I'm trying to map Alt + 4 which I use to jump from one email to the next (When the email is open in a separate window) to RCtrl + Tab, and want to map Alt + 5 which jumps to the previous email, to RCtrl + RShift + Tab.

Do you know what might be the error here?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that you can create combinations of more than two keys using the `&` operator. Here is an alternative that manually checks the status of the shift key:

```
RCtrl & Tab::
WinGet, Active_ID, ID, A
WinGet, Active_Process, ProcessName, ahk_id %Active_ID%
if (Active_Process = "Outlook.exe") {
    If GetKeyState("RShift","P")    {
        Send !5
        return
    }
    else    {
        Send !4
        return
    }
}
else {
    Send ^{tab}
}
return
```